# Can I buy some more unibadges with my unicoins?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

I mean seriously, I've saved up some unicoins and I want to buy more unibadges.

At the moment I have some but how can I buy more? The item disappeared from the Power-Up Store! Please do something to fix the bug!

[image: unibadges]

Answer (score 2):

To fix the bug you will need to understand quantum gravity. You can do that by logging in StackOverflow with Princess Celestia.

If you don't yet have unicorn logins you will have to add them in *my logins*.
[image]

Comment: Dear Princes Celestia,  

Today I learned that on April, 1 everypony around Meta seem to just go Pinkie and start to play pranks like there is no tomorrow. Also, I would humbly report that the shop still don't sell muffins. I wanted one!  

Still waiting for lunch,  
Your loyal mailpony, Derpy.